# Как создать hover эффект кнопок сайта animejs

Tags: javascript, css, svg, canvas

Зашел случайно на сайт [**animejs**](http://animejs.com/)

Очень понравились `hover` эффект их основных кнопок везде искал но подобного эффекта не нашел даже у них на сайте подобного нету

```css
.btn {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    line-height:2.3;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">button</div>
```

До эффекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вычисляет и изменяет элемент `svg` — `path`. Конкретная формула явно где-то в исходниках, но искать мне лень. Хотя не очень лень: http://animejs.com/documentation/assets/js/site.js Сразу же инициализация кнопок.

Comment: @Other спасибо  :D благодарья вам я сам дам ответ:)

Comment: Пожалуйста!....

Comment: http://animejs.com/documentation/assets/js/site.js   тут все есть

Comment: Anime =)) улыбнуло

Comment: @Demon __ ANT можно на ваш ответ взглянуть с другой стороны? Это очень хорошо, что вы спросили и сами ответили на свой вопрос. Это только приветствуется правилами сайта, но зачем решение забирать себе? Вам от этого **ноль репутации**, На ваш вопрос отвечали несколько людей и ответы хорошие, если бы вы отдали решение кому-то из них, то от вас ничего бы не убыло, а людям было бы +15. И был бы стимул в дальнейшем отвечать на ваши вопросы. Тем более вам подсказали, где искать решение. Вы можете перенести галочку на любой ответ по вашему выбору.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я им обоим дал по плюсь один а вопрос не принял потому что не подходил их решение.Если бы на вопрос ответил тот который подсказал я бы принял его ответ.А так мой ответ более подходит.И кстати я всегда плюсую тому кто отвечает на мой вопрос но тут во первых мой ответ был более верным во вторых у них у обоих по 500 ответов а у меня ноль хоть будет ответов на свой вопрос.

Comment: @Сожалею, что вы не поняли меня. Я сказал, что хорошо, что вы сами ответили.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну вот ребята как то так :)

Суть ясно ничего сложного нету

Ответил на основе ссылки который дал Other

```js
var createBouncyButtons = (function() {
  function createButton(el) {
    var pathEl = el.querySelector('path');
    var spanEl = el.querySelector('span');
    function hover() {
      anime.remove([pathEl, spanEl]);
      anime({
        targets: pathEl,
        d: 'M10,10 C10,10 50,7 90,7 C130,7 170,10 170,10 C170,10 172,20 172,30 C172,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,53 90,53 C50,53 10,50 10,50 C10,50 8,40 8,30 C8,20 10,10 10,10 Z',
        elasticity: 700,
        offset: 0
      });
      anime({
        targets: spanEl,
        scale: 1.15,
        duration: 800,
        offset: 0
      });
    }
    function down() {
      anime.remove([pathEl, spanEl]);
      anime({
        targets: pathEl,
        d: 'M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z',
        elasticity: 700,
        offset: 0
      });
      anime({
        targets: spanEl,
        scale: 1,
        duration: 800,
        offset: 0
      });
    }
    el.onmouseenter = hover;
    el.onmousedown = down;
    el.onmouseleave = down;
  }
  var buttonEls = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

  for (var i = 0; i < buttonEls.length; i++) {
    var el = buttonEls[i];
    createButton(el);
  }
})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button.blue {
  color: #5E89FB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<a class="button blue" href="documentation" target="_blank" style="opacity: 1;">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 180 60">
          <path d="M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z"></path>
        </svg>
        <span>Documentation</span>
      </a>
```

Comment: там половина не нужна ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский вы про js код?да но я устал наверное завтра отредатирую.. но вот никак не смог впихнуть слово документ в сам блок =(

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, не половина)))), а 90 %%%%

Comment: там слово в svg должно быть а не в html

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, нет, в html, у родителя поставить нужно вертикальное и горизонтальное выравнивание, иначе эффект не будет работать на тексте.

Comment: @Arthur  может быть - спорить не буду

Comment: @Air Удалил ненужный хлам щас смотрите

Comment: @Air  с лого тоже лишнее

Comment: @Demon__ANT, сделал текст по центру

Comment: @МаксимЛенский лого удалил ..

Comment: @Arthur щас постараюсь сделать так как вы сказали и перемщу текст внутр кнопки

Comment: Ooo  крут ребята мне нра плюсую

Answer (score 10):

Вроде похоже.

```js
let up = document.getElementById("up"),
  down = document.getElementById("down"),
  hoverBlock = document.getElementById("hover-block");

hoverBlock.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  up.beginElement();
  console.log
});
hoverBlock.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
  down.beginElement();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 70px;
  background: transparent;
}

#hover-block {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1111;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.8;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: '';
  transition: all .3s;
}

#hover-block:hover~p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  transition: all .3s;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2.7;
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="hover-block">
  </div>
  <svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="220" height="70" viewBox="0 0 220 70">
 <style>svg{background: transparent;  position:absolute;} </style>
  <path id="pt" d="M 20 20, C20 20  100 20 200 20, L200 50, C200 50  100 50 20 50Z"  fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="1">
    <animate id="up" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="0.3s" to="M 20 20, C20 20  100 10 200 20, L200 50, C200 50  100 60 20 50Z" />
       <animate id="down" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="0.3s" to="M 20 20, C20 20  100 20 200 20, L200 50, C200 50  100 50 20 50Z" /> 
 </path>
</svg>
  <p>GitHub</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Если не будет лень, завтра  пример на `css` сделаю

Comment: Ближе к истине, похоже действительно=)

Comment: (+), Можно ещё увеличение текста внутри сделать как в примере.

Comment: @Air  всё равно что твой пример что мой не похож на пример из вопроса

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, можно потратить еще часок, и сделать полностью аналогичным примеру из вопроса ответ. Я и ты показали вполне доходчивый пример. Если честно у меня нет желания тратить этот лишний час.... Если бы было лишнее время то вполне бы мог сделать.. пример выше я за 5 минут сделал...

Comment: @Air неплохо сделал мог бы доработать и сделать в точности такой же жаль =(

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, поверь, просто времени нет... Я на вопросы то отвечаю, что бы в тонусе оставаться...

Comment: @Air мне твой пример больше других понравился, на месте автора вопроса я тебе бы отдал решение.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, загляни в чат

Comment: эта анимация тоже не работает в firefox

Answer (score 8):

Анимация срабатывает по `hover` на красную область:

```css
#pt:hover {
  d: path("m 15,135 c 63,-16 122,-13 179,0 v 54 c -57,11 -117,14 -179,0 z");
  d: "m 15,135 c 63,-16 122,-13 179,0 v 54 c -57,11 -117,14.35755 -179,0 z";
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 110 500 530">
  <path id="pt" d="M 15,135 H 194 v 54 H 15 Z" fill="#ff2a2a"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Класс! А если ещё команды и кол-во точек будут совпадать, то можно прикрутить `css transition`. Два типа записи свойства это  для разных браузеров?

Comment: Работает только в `webkit` браузерах

Comment: действительно не работает в firefox , только автора ответ работает везде ...надо работать над этим

Comment: А жаль. Это ж какой простор для творчества был бы.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров  нет ... там вместо hover надо перепилить на onmouse...

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров  и кстати  посмотри что на SVG делают (only -webkit-)  https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedAnimals/index.html